# Using php if statement for html login form

Tags: php, html, if-statement, authentication

I am trying to link my html login form to a php file with if statement that when is true, links to another html page.

But when i enter username and password and hit enter , it links to php file that shows a blank page. (i am using xampp )
The code is below:

```
<form  action="init.php" method"post" class="form-signin" >
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username"       placeholder="userName" required="" autofocus="" />
  <input type="passWord" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required=""/>     

  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log in</button>   
</form>
```

And the php file's code is:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php 
if (isset($_POST["username"])){


$username = $_POST['Username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username =='myaccount' AND $password=='myaccount123') {
echo '<a href="student1.html"></a>';
} else if ($username =='myaccount1' AND $password=='myaccount1123') {
echo '<a href="student2.html"></a>';
}
else {
echo "You have not requested a login form!";
} }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

It is for a school project so thanks in advance.

Comment: A blank page often means there's an error.  Turn on error reporting, check the logs, etc.

Comment: `method"post"` where's the `=` ? Without it the form will submit using the default `get` method and therefore `$_POST['username']` will **never** be set.

Comment: `$username = $_POST['Username'];` that should be a lowercase 'username' too

Comment: Why first check if the username `isset`? Why not check when your button `isset`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all turn on error reporting (find it in php.ini in xamp/php/bin)

The problem is most likely the fact  that you're doing:

`$username = $_POST["Username"]`

and you're sending:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="username"       placeholder="userName" required="" autofocus="" />
```

Capitalisation matters here (i.e. 'Username' vs 'username')